# Creating Family Tree with Neo4J

Tags: json, neo4j

I have a set of data for a family tree in Neo4J and am trying to build a Cypher query that produces a JSON data set similar to the following:

```
{Name:  "Bob",
      parents: [
          {Name:  "Roger",
             parents: [
                Name: "Robert",
                Name: "Jessica"
             ]},
          {Name:  "Susan",
             parents: [
                Name: "George",
                Name: "Susan"
             ]}
      ]}
```

My graph has a relationship of PARENT between MEMBER nodes (i.e. MATCH (p.Member)-[:PARENT]->(c.Member) ).  I found [Nested has_many relationships in cypher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20682024/nested-has-many-relationships-in-cypher) and [neo4j cypher nested collect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21896382/neo4j-cypher-nested-collect) which ends up grouping all parents together for the main child node I am searching for.

Adding some clarity based on feedback:

Every member has a unique identifier.  The unions are currently all associated with the PARENT relationship.  Everything is indexed so that performance will not suffer.  When I run a query to just get back the node graph I get the results I expect.  I'm trying to return an output that I can use for visualization purposes with D3.  Ideally this will be done with a Cypher query as I'm using the API to access neo4j from the frontend being built.

Adding a sample query:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[:PARENT*1..5]->(c:Person)
WHERE c.FirstName = 'Bob'
RETURN p.FirstName, c.FirstName
```

This query returns a list of each parent for five generations, but instead of showing the hierarchy, it's listing 'Bob' as the child for each relationship.  Is there a Cypher query that would show each relationship in the data at least?  I can format it as I need to from there...

Comment: More info please; are you using the REST API or an embedded DB?  If you're using the REST API, your problem is simplified maybe to the task of transforming the JSON that the REST API spits out, into this structure you're looking for.   http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might also have a look at [Rik van Bruggens Blog on his family data](http://blog.bruggen.com/2014/01/leftovers-from-holidays-genealogy-graphs.html?q=family&view=magazine):

Regarding your query

You already create a path pattern here: `(p:Person)-[:PARENT*1..5]->(c:Person)` you can assign it to a variable `tree` and then operate on that variable, e.g. returning the tree, or `nodes(tree)` or `rels(tree)` or operate on that collection in other ways:

```
MATCH tree = (p:Person)-[:PARENT*1..5]->(c:Person)
WHERE c.FirstName = 'Bob'
RETURN nodes(tree), rels(tree), tree, length(tree),
       [n in nodes(tree) | n.FirstName] as names
```

See also the cypher reference card: http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypher-refcard and the online training http://neo4j.com/online-training to learn more about Cypher.

Don't forget to

```
create index on :Person(FirstName);
```

Answer (score 8):

Genealogical data might comply with the GEDCOM standard and include two types of nodes: Person and Union.  The Person node has its identifier and the usual demographic facts. The Union nodes have a union_id and the facts about the union.  In GEDCOM, Family is a third element bringing these two together.  But in Neo4j, I found it suitable to also include the union_id in Person nodes.  I used 5 relationships: father, mother, husband, wife and child. The family is then two parents with an inward vector and each child with an outward vector.  The image illustrates this.  This is very handy for visualizing connections and generating hypotheses.  For example, consider the attached picture and my ancestor Edward G Campbell, the product of union 1917 where three brothers married three Vaught sisters from union 8944 and two married Gaither sisters from union 2945.  Also, in the upper left, how Mahala Campbell married her step-brother John Greer Armstrong.  Next to Mahala is an Elizabeth Campbell who is connected by marriage to other Campbell, but is likely directly related to them.  Similarly, you can hypothesize about Rachael Jacobs in the upper right and how she might relate to the other Jacobs.  [image: Notice the query. From the few initial nodes visualized, you can click to open others.] 
I use bulk inserts which can populate ~30000 Person nodes and ~100,000 relationships in just over a minute.  I have a small .NET function that returns the JSon from a dataview; this generic solution works with any dataview so it is scalable. I'm now working on adding other data, such as locations (lat/long), documentation (particularly that linking folks, such as a census), etc.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest building a method to flatten out your data into an array.  If they objects don't have UUIDs you would probably want to give them IDs as you flatten and then have a parent_id key for each record.

You can then run it as a set of cypher queries (either making multiple requests to the query REST API, or using the batch REST API) or alternatively dump the data to CSV and use cypher's `LOAD CSV` command to load the objects.

An example cypher command with params would be:

```
CREATE (:Member {uuid: {uuid}, name: {name}}
```

And then running through the list again with the parent and child IDs:

```
MATCH (m1:Member {uuid: {uuid1}}), (m2:Member {uuid: {uuid2}})
CREATE m1<-[:PARENT]-m2
```

Make sure to have an index on the ID for members!

Comment: This is close to what I am looking for.  Is there no way to generate the set through a single query?  Say I want to see the tree for four or five generations from a given person.  I can get the graph to show the data - I just need a way to morph it via cypher if possible.  Otherwise, I'll have to stick with the raw data returning from the base query and have to process it into the format I'm looking for.

Comment: It might be possible to get it using only cypher, but I suspect it wouldn't be worth the effort.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misread.  I thought you wanted to take JSON and turn it into a neo4j database with cypher, but you want the other way around

Answer (score 2):

The only way I have found thus far to get the data I am looking for is to actually return the relationship information, like so:

```
MATCH ft = (person {firstName: 'Bob'})<-[:PARENT]-(p:Person)
RETURN EXTRACT(n in nodes(ft) | {firstName: n.firstName}) as parentage
ORDER BY length(ft);
```

Which will return a dataset I am then able to morph:

```
["Bob", "Roger"]
["Bob", "Susan"]
["Bob", "Roger", "Robert"]
["Bob", "Susan", "George"]
["Bob", "Roger", "Jessica"]
["Bob", "Susan", "Susan"]
```

Comment: I wrote this answer while Michael was writing his :)  Both are on the same track so gave the resolved answer to him.